# i want to remove coma and plus (+) operator from a string

Tags: javascript, str-replace

I want to remove plus(+) sign and coma from a string.
here is the code.

```
actualValue.push(parseFloat(wholeValues[i].replace(/,/g, '')))
```

Comment: coma is successfully removed but unable to remove + sign

Comment: You can chain them `actualValue.push(parseFloat(wholeValues[i].replace(',', '').replace('+', '')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace twice.

```
const value = parseFloat(wholeValues[i].replaceAll(',', '').replaceAll('+', ''))
actualValue.push(value)
```

Comment: It should be `replaceAll`, or else you'll only remove the first occurrence of each of those characters.   Try `yourString.replaceAll('+', '').replaceAll(',', '');`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
wholeValues[i].replace(/[+,]/g, '')
```

or

```
wholeValues[i].replace(/,/g, '').replace(/+/g, '')
```

The first one is faster a little bit.